# css border-style double 1px gap chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

3px double border on the left or right side of a div, however in chrome it is leaving a 1px gap at the top of the border. I have tried looking extensively to see if this is a browser bug or for some kind of solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/QSm2Z/2/

If you view the code in firefox/ie you get continuous black bar, in chrome and on my phone/tablet I am getting a 1px gap at the top of each div which breaks the black bar

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.test {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-right: 3px double #c7c7c7;
    border-left: 3px double #c7c7c7;
    background-color: #06F;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom-style:
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a feature :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Observations

There appears to be a glitch in the corner-shaping algorithm that leaves a mitered edge in preparation of meeting a border on a perpendicular edge even though there is not one.

I doubt this is the intended behavior, even though the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-style) states that:

> This specification does not define how borders of different styles
>   should be joined in the corner.

You can see evidence of the mitered join with a 2 pixel solid border (screenshot):

[image]

If you look very closely, you can see the manifestation of another potential problem: the edges of the top and side borders don't touch (screenshot):

[image]

## Workaround

This is complex/inelegant by comparison, but one way to fix the problem is to hide both the top and bottom edge of the offending elements. You'll need to adjust the dimensions for your actual site.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QSm2Z/10/

```
.test{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 152px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.test:after {
    width: 100px;
    height: 102px;
    content: "";
    top: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #06F;
    border-left: 26px double #000;
    border-right: 26px double #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I tried myself using a transparent border and/or zero length border but had no luck getting it to solve the problem, thankfully just changing my production code to top: -1px; instead of top: 0; solved this for me as I was already using a :before statement on this. Looks like another one for the long list of browser bugs. You would think such a simple basic statement like this would be bug free!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a browser bug - it doesn't happen with regular `solid` borders - check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/QSm2Z/8/

Maybe related to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=61702